# KDE apps look ugly over ssh

Tags: ssh, kde

I am on a Kubuntu machine and sometimes reach another Xubuntu machine over ssh, and launch some KDE apps from there, these apps look really weird while the GTK apps look normal. Here are some screenshots:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

For comparison, the kate editor launched locally looks like this:

[image]

A gtk app (ristretto image viewer) over ssh:

[image]

Comment: what's *ugly*? what is the desired result? would you mind annotating the screenshots, so we know what you mean with each?

Comment: I have added a 'normal' window that is launched locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the remote machine, do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install kde-style-oxygen qt4-qtconfig
qtconfig &
```

After opening `qtconfig`, choose Oxygen as gui style, and change the 
button background and window background color as you prefer, then save on exit.